# Naming variables with an incrementing number. Python

Tags: python, object, increment

I need to create several hundred instances of an Object (rack) but i can't find the proper way to write this in. What i need is something like this but more elegant:

```
class Rack:

    def __init__(self):
        self._listeMedNoder = []

Rack1 = Rack()

Rack2 = Rack()

Rack3 = Rack()
```

etc... but up to say 100.

Comment: It is possible. But it's not such a good practice. A more proper method for this case would be to use a dictionary.

Comment: Don't do this. Use a `list `or `dict`

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is by creating a List instance, and filling that with your objects.

```
racks = []
for _ in range(n):
    racks.append(Rack)
```

Where n = the amount of instances you want to create. Note that `range()` is exclusive, so you'll have to increase it by 1 to create enough instances of `Rack`. To access the classes you can call `racks[index]` where the index is the class you want to access. Note that lists start from index '0', so `racks[1]` will be the second element (in this case, the second class).

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to name them? If not, just make a list:

```
racks = [Rack() for _ in range(100)]
```

You can then access any instance of `Rack` using the list index:

```
print racks[0]
```